# Cannot declare 'ReactiveFormsModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation

Tags: angular

my angular version is this:
[Angular cli version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11Nr.png)

i create a component its name is Register
i run ng serve whole angular project throw exception like this:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:21:5 - error NG6001: Cannot declare 'ReactiveFormsModule' in an NgModule as it's not a part of the current compilation.
```

and its error photo  is :
[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFcDh.png)

can any one help me?

Comment: can you show your `app.module.ts`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like you have declared ReactiveFormsModule in 'declarations' section. Modules should be imported. It should not be declared.

Answer (score 2):

```
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
   // ReactiveFormsModule---remove from declarations and add in import
  ],
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule]
```

Comment: Your answer might be technically right. But you should add some explenations to it. This would improve your answer.